# Fixed position for sidebar and mainpanel in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have a fixed-width sidebar in my RShiny application which stays in place when resizing the window.

I have managed getting a fixed-width sidebar, but there is still white spacing between the sidebar and the main panel. It seems like there should be a straight-forward solution to this, but my searches has this far been futile.

Here is a minimal example based on the 'Old Faithful Geyser Data' template. I have added tags which keeps the side panel to a fixed width.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          tags$head(
              tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 240px; }"),
              tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 290px; }"),
              tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 280px; }")
          ),
         sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
      ),
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The normal output looks good.

[image: Default]

When dragging the window the sidebar get very wide, taking valuable screen estate from the main panel.

[image: SpacingSidebar]

When fixing the width of the sidebar panel it stays in shape when expanding the window, but the main panel is not able to utilize the full area. The desired reaction is that the sidebar panel stays in size and the main panel can utilize all the available space.

[image: StretchedSidebar]

Anyone having any ideas for how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: not completely the desired functionality, but would `sidebarPanel(width = 3,...)` be an option for you? The sidebar would not be fixed to a width, but the ratio would be fixed,..?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have tried this too, but I was not really satisfied with it. I am using RShiny to explore a large interactive table of data, often stretching it across more than one computer monitor to see as much as possible, so all 'screen-estate' matters here, and if I make the side-panel too thin the input looks strange for normal window width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it OK like this?:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 240px; }"),
    tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 290px; }"),
    tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 280px; }")
  ),

  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  div(
    style = "display:flex; align-items:flex-start",
    wellPanel( # sidebar
      sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      textInput("text", "Enter text:")
    ),
    div( # main panel
      style = "flex-grow:1; resize:horizontal; overflow: hidden",
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! Almost there. But when I run this the input-panel ends up above the figure. Would it be possible to get it to the left side of the main plot?

Comment: @Jakob37 Strange, I don't get this behavior. I'm using Chrome, and you ? Could you try `style = "display:flex; align-items:flex-start; flex-direction:row"`.

Comment: Adding the line `style = "float:left;"` within the wellPanel in this solution gave me exactly what I was after. Great, thank you!

Comment: I use Chromium on Ubuntu. I tried to update the styling according to your comment - in that case it still ends up on different rows.

Comment: Aha, got it now. I normally run through R-studios viewer. When running it directly in Chrome your inital solution worked great. Thanks!